# Absolute URL incorrect when converted from relative URL Android JSoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to parse out navigation links from various sites.

I've been having issues with one particular site which uses a relative format prefixed with `./` Here is the code snippet with relevant param values in comments:

```
// url = http://megatokyo.com/strip/1456
// selector = ".next a"
// ele = <a href="./strip/1457">Next</a>
// attr = "href"
Element ele = doc.select(selector).get(index);
ele.setBaseUri(url);
String absoluteUrl = ele.absUrl(attr).trim().replaceAll("\n", "");
```

Jsoup returns:

```
http://megatokyo.com/strip/strip/1457
```

when in fact the real link is:

```
http://megatokyo.com/strip/1457
```

From my understanding Jsoup is giving the correct link here as `./` refers to the current directory (`http://megatokyo.com/strip/`) meaning that the anchor is done incorrectly on the site. However Chrome, Firefox and IE all resolve the relative URL to point to the next strip instead of `/strip/strip/1457`. Is there any way I can correct for this behaviour without breaking relative URLs in other cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem:

If you have a look at the header of the html source, you will find:

```
<head>
    ...
    <base href="http://megatokyo.com/" />
</head>
```

What does it mean?

For all relative urls in the document, this will be used as the base (so this is the current directory `./`). See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Fix:

Jsoup allready detects the `<base>` tag and `ele.absUrl("href")` would (and does, just tested it) return `http://megatokyo.com/strip/1457` but you are overriding the correct settings with `ele.setBaseUri(url);`, so remove this line of code.

If you want to handle setting the correct base yourself, just parse the head for a `<base>` element:

```
String url = "http://megatokyo.com/strip/1456";

Element base = doc.select("head > base[href]").first();

String baseUrl = base!=null ? base.attr("href") : url;

Element ele = doc.select("#comic > div > div.navcontrols.top > ul > li.next > a").first();
ele.setBaseUri(baseUrl);

System.out.println(ele.attr("abs:href"));
```

Comment: Very well explained. Unfortunately I forgot to add a relevant piece of info to my question - I am not using Jsoup to load the URL in this instance, only to parse out the attributes. As such baseURI is not set implicitly. Is there any way to parse out the baseURI from this document (which contains the full source) other than using selectors to parse it out manually?

Comment: @alexgophermix ok, was wondering, why you had to call setBaseUri. Updated my answer: just parse the head for the base tag and handle it. Out of curiosity: why are you not using jsoup to get the page/what are you using?

Comment: I have a single async network task that's loaded with various callbacks and configurations and is used in other places throughout the app that don't require document parsing. There's probably room for improvement but it's working for now ¯\_(ツ)_/¯